# Toggle icon on Like with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, frontend

I have made a like button powered by ajax and I have defined a function that it refresh the text. Now I want to change it for updating from font awesome fa-heart-o to fa-heart and viceversa. How can I do it? see the code below

base.html

```
<script>
                     $(document).ready(function(){
                            function updateText(btn, newCount, iconClass, verb){
                verb = verb || "";
                $(btn).html(newCount + '<i class="' + iconClass + '"></i>' + verb )  
                     btn.attr("data-likes", newCount)
                    }

                        $(".like-btn").click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault()
                        var this_ = $(this)
                        var likeUrl = this_.attr("data-href")
                        var likeCount = parseInt(this_.attr("data-likes")) | 0
                        var addLike = likeCount + 1
                        var removeLike = likeCount - 1

                        if (likeUrl){
                             $.ajax({
                            url: likeUrl,
                            method: "GET",
                            data: {},
                            success: function(data){
                                console.log(data)
                                var newLikes;
                                if (data.liked){
                                    updateText(this_, addLike, "fa fa-heart")


                                } else {
                                    updateText(this_, removeLike, "fa fa-heart-o")


                                }
                            }, error: function(error){
                                console.log(error)
                                console.log("error")
                            }
                            })
                        }

                        })
                    })

         </script>
```

and button like html

```
<a class='like-btn' data-href='{{ comentario.get_api_like_url }}' data-likes='{{ comentario.likes.count }}' 
href='{{ comentario.get_like_url }}'>{{ comentario.likes.count }}

{% if request.user in comentario.likes.all %}
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
{% else %}
    <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
{% endif %}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your success callback, use updateText to define the element.

**Example**

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    var newLikes;
    if (data.liked) {
        updateText(this_, addLike, "fa fa-heart")

    } else {
        updateText(this_, removeLike, "fa fa-heart-o")
        // remove one like
    }
}, error: function(error) {
    console.log(error)
    console.log("error")
}


function updateText(btn, newCount, iconClass, verb) {
    verb = verb || "";
    $(btn).html(newCount + '<i class="fa' + iconClass + '"></i>' + verb)
    btn.attr("data-likes", newCount)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but when i click on it it appears like undefined instead of the icon heart. I try also removing updateText(this_, addLike) and it does not work.

Comment: Can you inspect element and see what classes are there after clicking ?

Comment: updated my answers there were some spaces in class names may be that caused this issue.

Comment: yes, the class is class="like-btn", which is inside <a></a>

Comment: Sorry but can you share screenshot of your inspected HTML? Thanks.

Comment: Undefined is there is because in `updateText` method you are using `verb` but when you are calling `updateText` you did not pass verb thus it shows `undefined` because verb is undefined.

Comment: I have updated my answer please have a look and try that. I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: see my question updated. When I click on it, it appears a small white square, so I think that it does not recognize the fa fa-heart

Answer (score 1):

[image]

here is the screen picture, the class is like-btn